# How to expunge Wallet Manager

Tags: wireless, kwallet

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  The KDE wallet system seems to have done me in again. How can I expunge it so that my system will behave as though it never existed?  Merely unchecking the "enable KDE wallet system" box in System Settings doe not seem to be sufficient  in the case of secrets relating to wireless internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove `kwallet` without any issues.

Run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove kwallet
```

You might want to first run `sudo apt remove kwallet --simulate` just to make sure it won't remove any other dependencies you need.